# How can I make my menu return to the original display after a user chooses an option, and the code finishes?

Tags: c++, console-application

I’m currently working on a C++ console app, migrating from C# to C++. I’ve seen a cool feature somewhere from someone else’s project ages ago but i’m not sure how to replicate this. What happens is when a user selects an option like this

[1] Option 1
[2] Option 2

Choice:

After they select it, it will of course do what whatever correlates with that option. Once done, the code then shows the menu back to the “original state” with the options and the choices so the use can again select another one if it’s there. How can I replicate this?

Comment: More information is needed. The standard way to repeat functionality is with a loop. Do you not know what a loop is *(hopefully you do, but I cannot assume that based solely on your question)*, do you not know how to use a loop in this situation, or something else? Short, example code might help illustrate where you are coming from. (If I were to guess, I'd speculate that you have tried to jam too much into one monolithic function instead of making your code more modular.)

Comment: Put all "functions" of the program in separate functions, including sub-menus. When one is finished, it returns to the previous function, which displays its menu.

Comment: Sounds like a simply state machine. Each state enter function prints the menu options and the state methods react on the input and can move to any other state including tha last one which was active before.